# Hide rows based on length of longest column vba

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a set of 7 non-consecutive columns to cycle through and I want to hide all the rows after the end of the longest column (cells that contain no value).

```
For Each Y In Array(4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40)
For X = 16 To 65
    If wks.Cells(X, Y).Value = "" Then
        wks.Cells(X, Y).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else: wks.Cells(X, Y).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next X
Next Y
```

This would cover it except for the fact that the columns are different lengths and by the time the macro is finished, some rows that contain data have been hidden. I know what I have isn't quite correct, I'm just not sure how to tweak it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the columns and use Find to find the last with a value.

```
Sub test()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet
wks.Rows("16:65").Hidden = False
Dim y
Dim j As Range
Dim currentmax As Long
For Each y In Array(4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40)
    Set j = wks.Range(wks.Cells(16, y), wks.Cells(65, y)).Find("*", wks.Cells(16, y), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not j Is Nothing Then
        If j.Row > currentmax Then currentmax = j.Row
    End If
Next y

If currentmax > 16 Then
    wks.Rows(currentmax + 1 & ":65").Hidden = True
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This one did it. I just had to get the .find to search in values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets(1)

    Dim myCol       As Variant
    Dim myRow       As Long
    Dim recordRow   As Long : recordRow = 65

    For Each myCol In Array(4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40)
        For myRow = 16 To 65
            If wks.Cells(myRow, myCol).Value = "" Then
                If recordRow < myRow Then recordRow = myRow
                Exit For
            End If
        Next myRow
    Next myCol

    If myRow < 65 Then wks.Rows("65:" & myRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

- Introduce a variable `recordRow`, which keeps the lowest row of the columns;
- Once the variable makes the check, the first for loop exits;
- At the end you hide the EntireRow, starting from `16` and ending with the `recordRow`;
- `If myRow < 16` is needed to make sure that `myRow` has some values assigned;

Comment: Thanks for your response! This actually appears to be hiding all the rows that contain data, plus the next two after that.

Comment: It still appears to be hiding rows based on the length of the final column. I entered data to make one of the middle columns the longest and it was hidden.

Comment: @Cm5415 - I see, I have changed it correspondingly.